# How to resolve the django import from view function?

Tags: python, django, django-1.8

On my way to learn django, I have been following this [book](http://gsl.mit.edu/media/programs/south-africa-summer-2015/materials/djangobook.pdf)

My views.py contains -

```
def addPublisher(request):
    if request == 'POST':
        form = PublisherForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid:
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('add_publisher/thanks/')
        else:
            form = PublisherForm()
        return render_to_response('book/addPublisher.html',{'form':form})
```

My urls.py has following code-

```
from views import *

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^add/$',addPublisher)
    ]
```

While importing `addPublisher` function to my urls.py, I am getting this error.

```
name 'addPublisher' is not defined
```

Comment: It looks to me as if your views.py is from one of the webapps, you should say "from webapp.view import *"
To be simple, is your views.py and urls.py in same folder?

Comment: import like this: from views import addPublisher, not like this: from views import * - this way you may get a more informative error message (e.g. maybe your addPublisher is in another views file in another folder etc as django projects usually have many of them)

Comment: Note that The Django Book was written with Django 1.0 in mind, which was released 11 years ago. There are a lot of incompatibilities between 1.0 and 1.8, it would probably be a lot easier to learn using an up-to-date resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your urls.py file is probably not in the same app (folder) than your views.py. 
You are getting this error saying that addPublisher **is not defined** because it's literally not *there*, by *there* I mean the app where urls.py is located.

If that particular views.py above is located in another app, please import it with something like 
 
 **from [name of app].views import ***
Anyway, showing us the layout of your project will help us give you a more direct and specific answer! Thank you.